# Is it possible to set latest firefox(firefox/26.0) as eclipse internal web browser in eclipse/linux?

Tags: linux, eclipse, firefox

I'm Using eclipse(Version: Kepler Service Release1) and I want to set firefox(26.0 or latest) as the internal web browser. Is it possible change/update the internal web browser in eclipse(linux) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO NO. Currently internal web browser is a plug-in in eclipse NOT fully featured web browser. But you can associate HTML/HTM files to be opened directly in Firefox. Refer below picture

[image]

Comment: Yes, we can add firefox but html/htm files opened in external browser. It's the main problem but I want to open files in internal browser.

Comment: I have tried to update the internal browser version but failed, but thanks for quick reply :)